# Beamer Multiframe Bibliography Hides Everything after First Entry

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, lyx, allowframebreaks

I have a Beamer presentation, with stepwise uncover (to uncover each bullet in each slide in a step-wise manner).

The bibliography is too large to fit on a single slide, so I've used `allowframebreaks` as a frame option for the bibliography. Unfortunately, this has the unintended consequence of displaying the first bibliography item on the first bibliography frame and dimming the rest (even on the subsequent frames).

How do I get the full bibliography to display?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to surround the bibliography with `\only<1>{` and `}`. This shows the entire bibliography without uncovering any items, while keeping the framebreaks.